# Get a td element's indexes in a dynamically generated html table with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html `table` which is generated dynmically from an ajax call. It can have a variable number of rows and will always have 7 columns.

What I want to know is how to get a `td`'s indexes in the table with JavaScript/JQuery. I'm mostly interested in the column number but the row number would be a bonus.

I have the following handler:

```
$("#my-table").on("click", "td" ,function () {
    var my_row = $(this).parent();
});
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You say "coordinates", but by description of you problem, it appears you want indexes. If I'm correct, then what you want is supper easy. Index is 0 based tho, so if you want a human count, you'll need to add 1.

---

---

Keep in mind, when dealing with "dynamic" elements, it's best to use a static parent to assign events. If you don't know a static parent ID, you can always make use of DOM, however, some may recommend against it due to "performance" issues. I've been using `$(document)` for 6 years now and haven't had a single customer complaint. You decide.

```
$(document).on("click", "td" ,function () {
    var index_row = $(this).parent().index() + 1,
        index_column = $(this).index() + 1;
    // KEEP IN MIND ^ I added "1" to each as the "index" is "0" based. 
    // See documentation link below
});
```

## **Example on jsFiddle**

- [**jQuery index()**](http://api.jquery.com/index/)
- [***jQuery .on() [Read for better understanding of dynamic events]***](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: sorry I do mean indexes. I've updated the question.

Comment: @nettux443 no prob, just updated with example

Answer (score 2):

You can use cells `cellIndex` and rows `rowIndex` property to get x and y position in table.

Try this:

```
$("#my-table").on("click", "td" ,function () {
  var x=this.cellIndex;
  var y=this.parentNode.rowIndex;
  console.log(x,y);
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nMhmS/322/)**